# Submit text in EditText when using RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am currently trying to write a text in an EditText and then send this text.
Writing the text in the EditText works fine with the following code:

> productInputField.sendKeys("Test");

The problem now is to send this text. Pressing the ENTER key on the keyboard is unfortunately not possible with the RemoteWebDriver. I tried to send the ENTER key directly to the EditText:

> productInputField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

With this method only a number (here the 7) is inserted into the EditText. Unfortunately the text is not sent.

I thank you in advance for any help that could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you can try with "\n" in your input last productInputField.sendKeys("Test\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using the following code:

> driver.executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "search"));

See also: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/

Answer (score 0):

The ENTER key has two common functionality. One is for submitting something, another for go to the next line. `Keys.ENTER` is for submitting. You should use `Keys.RETURN`